# Change touch responder to other view in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, drag-and-drop, touch, first-responder

I want to make a drag and drop action in iPhone: when I touch down to a button A, a new view B appears at that location, and if I keep dragging my finger without lifting it, the new view B will be dragged around.

The problem is, when I touch down to button A, it is the one that will respond to the touchesMoved method. I can of course pass it manually to the view B, but it's not definitive, and when my finger moves out of the bounds of button A, now it's the background view which will respond to touchesMoved. Is there any simple way to pass the "touch responder" definitively to view B?

Comment: Are you using TouchCancelled and TouchEnded to disassociate the object with the input?

Comment: If I haven't lift my finger, I don't think touchesEnded and touchesCancelled would be called, wouldn't they?

Comment: Oh sorry, I miss-understood the problem. No you are right, they wouldn't be called (unless there was an interruption and then TouchCancelled would call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just forward the touch events

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet*) touches withEvent:(UIEvent*)event{
   [otherView touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

and than handle the touch in the other View.
Before yout touch cancels/ends the touchfunction of the superview aren't called

Comment: As I said, this does not work if my finger is outside the bounds of button A. I will need to do this for every possible responders in the view.

Comment: do you use `[touch locationInView:buttonA];`?  
than try `[touch locationInView:[self superview]];`  
go in any App you want, touch on a button, move your finger out of it and you will see, that its allways "touchedDown"  
its not normal that the button loses the touch

Comment: The problem is not with touchesBegan I think, but with touchesMoved. Because when I move my finger outside of A's bounds, it will no longer receive touch events, and can no longer forward them to otherView.

Comment: surely it does, it keeps the firstresponder as long as touchEnded/touchCanceled isn't called is it possible, that you add your view to the buttonsview and not to the superview of the button?

Comment: do you use a action or touchEvent to create the view?